# Display DropDownList in aspx-page

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I created dropdownlist in C# code. How to display this ddlist in aspx page?
My code:

```
<%
    DropDownList list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list = new DropDownList();
        list.ID = i + "_ID";
        %>
        <!-- how to display drop down list here??? -->
        <%
    }
 %>
```

Comment: could you please add your code?If you added it will be shown when you open the page in browser if it's `Visible` property is not set `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have in aspx code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DenemeWebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="DenemeWebApplication.DenemeWebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Panel ID="PanelAmk" runat="server">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code creates a web page with a panel named `PanelAmk`, and nothing more.

Here is what I have in aspx.cs code(C# code) which basically adds a `DropDownList` to the page created above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DenemeWebApplication
{
    public partial class DenemeWebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList dropdownlistAmk = new DropDownList();//creates a new dropdownlist
            dropdownlistAmk.Items.Add("amk");//adds an item to dropdownlistAmk created above
            PanelAmk.Controls.Add(dropdownlistAmk);//and adds dropwdownlistAmk to PanelAmk

        }
    }
}
```

What you are missing is adding the `DropDownList` to the control with `...Controls.Add(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've created the control in code, The control doesn't yet exist on the page.  You need to add it somewhere on the page.  For example, you can decoratively create a asp:Panel with an ID of "myPanel" and then add ddlist through code as follows:

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(ddlist);
```

For a full description of this process, take a look at the following MSDN article: [How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)